# Не выводит данные по конкретной записи (show) Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel5

Очень нужна ваша помощь, что-то подтупливаю с утра)
Есть куча записей

```
@if($products->count())
    @foreach($products as $product)
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <h2>{{ $product->product_title }}</h2>
                @if($product->product_status == "true")
                <h4>Начало торгов: {{ $product->product_start_trading }}</h4>
                @else
                <h4>Аренда</h4>
                @endif
                <p>{{ str_limit($product->product_description, 250, '...') }}</p>
                <p><a href="{{ url('/object', $product->product_id) }}">Подробнее »</a></p>
            </div>
    @endforeach
@endif
```

У каждой записи есть ссылка "Подробнее", по нажатию которой мы должны переходить на страницу show. В контролере:

```
public function show(Product $product)
{
    return view('product.show', compact('product'));
}
```

В роутах:

```
Route::get('object/{id}', 'ProductController@show');
```

На странице show:

```
<div class="container">
    <ul class="nav nav-pills">
        <li class="active"><a href="{{ url('/') }}">Все объекты</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Продажа</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Аренда</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div class="blog-post">
        <h2 class="blog-post-title">{{ $product->product_title }}</h2>
            <p class="blog-post-meta">January 1, 2014 by <a href="#">Mark</a></p>
            <p>{{ $product->product_description }}</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

На страницу переходит, нужный id-шник видит, проблема в том, что данные не выводит. В результате вижу только эту строку:

```
<p class="blog-post-meta">January 1, 2014 by <a href="#">Mark</a></p>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы пытаетесь пользоваться [Model binding](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/routing#route-model-binding), но в роуты передаете параметр `id`, хотя в вашем случае нужно `product`:

```
Route::get('object/{product}', 'ProductController@show');
```

А так получается что не срабатывает привязка по модели и на вьюху идет пустой объект `Product`, и по этой причине у вас нет данных на странице.

По умолчанию идет поиск по `id`, в вашем же случае нужно добавить в класс `Product` метод `getRouteKeyName` чтобы изменить поле для поиска:

```
public function getRouteKeyName()
{
    return 'product_id';
}
```

Comment: Сразу выдает ошибку:
SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'id' in 'where clause' (SQL: select * from `products` where `id` = 13 limit 1). Исходя из этой ошибки, могу сказать, что она ищет в базе id = 13, а надо product_id = 13. Как это сделать, не подскажите?

Comment: @YuriGo обновил ответ

Comment: Большое спасибо)